# Pandas - Merging 3rd data frame not merging on key values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am new to python and data analysis, so I apologise if this is very basic, but I am a little bit stuck

I have 3 data frames, schools 1, 2 & 3. Each has a Unique Reference Number (URN) and then additional data about the schools

In the dataset URN1 is an int, URN2 is an object and URN3 is a float. I have tried to convert them all to str and complete the merge

```
schools1['URN'] = schools1['URN'].astype(str)
schools2['URN'] = schools2['URN'].astype(str)
schools3['URN'] = schools3['URN'].astype(str)
```

```
merge1 = schools1.merge(schools2, how='left', on='URN', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
schoolsCombined = schools1.merge(schools3, how = 'left', on='URN', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
```

1 & 2 seem to merge fine as a string, 1 & 3 seem to merge fine as an object, but using this scenario, all the data is being dropped from the 3rd data frame in the process, or if using an outer join added to the bottom, but from my limited knowledge I can't work out why it doesn't seem to be recognising the URN's as matching

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 26451 entries, 0 to 26450
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   URN             26451 non-null  object 
 1   LANAME          26451 non-null  object 
 2   LA              26451 non-null  int64  
 3   ESTAB           26451 non-null  int64  
 4   LAESTAB         26451 non-null  int64  
 5   SCHNAME         26451 non-null  object 
 6   STREET          26371 non-null  object 
 7   LOCALITY        14966 non-null  object 
 8   ADDRESS3        2239 non-null   object 
 9   TOWN            25889 non-null  object 
 10  POSTCODE        26416 non-null  object 
 11  SCHSTATUS       26451 non-null  object 
 12  OPENDATE        2570 non-null   object 
 13  CLOSEDATE       2589 non-null   object 
 14  MINORGROUP      26451 non-null  object 
 15  SCHOOLTYPE      26451 non-null  object 
 16  ISPRIMARY       26451 non-null  int64  
 17  ISSECONDARY     26451 non-null  int64  
 18  ISPOST16        26451 non-null  int64  
 19  AGELOW          26446 non-null  float64
 20  AGEHIGH         26446 non-null  float64
 21  GENDER          26444 non-null  object 
 22  RELCHAR         26079 non-null  object 
 23  ADMPOL          25487 non-null  object 
 24  OFSTEDRATING    21631 non-null  object 
 25  OFSTEDLASTINSP  21670 non-null  object 
 26  LA_y            0 non-null      object 
 27  ESTAB_y         0 non-null      object 
 28  PERCTOT         0 non-null      float64
 29  PPERSABS10      0 non-null      object
```

Might be worth mentioning that the data for the 3rd data frame as a decimal, though I didn't think that would matter given the conversion of the data type, but in the other 2 it is interger

Can anyone help me understand the problem I am having? Is it related to the URN being retained as an object?

Comment: mixing types is not a good idea as you lose the efficiency of the dataframe...  so one solution is to modify the data in the dataframes so that they are consistent (maybe add columns if necessary to achieve this).

Comment: ...or convert everything to objects (this is least efficient, but will then merge successfully).